# Win API BitBlt() отображение разных картинок

Tags: c, winapi, graphics

Мне надо вывести в окно картинки из 2-х файлов, они формируют рамку окна с нестандартным интерфейсом. Получается выводить только из одного файла, не пойму почему. Если комментирую код, выводящий первую картинку, то вторая выводится, обе одновременно - нет.

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (  NULL,  TEXT ( ".\\..\\..\\..\\slujob\\rbq\\grafika\\ramka goriz.bmp" ),  IMAGE_BITMAP,  0,  0,  LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION  );
    if (hBitmap == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(IdGlavOkna, TEXT("Файл не найден"), TEXT("Загрузка изображения"), MB_OK | MB_ICONHAND);
        DestroyWindow(IdGlavOkna);
        return 1;
    }
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
hdc = GetDC(IdGlavOkna);
memBit = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(memBit, hBitmap);
ReleaseDC(IdGlavOkna, hdc);

hdc = BeginPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);

BitBlt (  hdc,  0,  0,  WirinaGlavOkna,  WirinaRamki,  memBit,  0,  0,   SRCCOPY  );
BitBlt (  hdc,  0,  VysotaGlavOkna - WirinaRamki,  WirinaGlavOkna, WirinaRamki,  memBit,  0,  0,  SRCCOPY  );

//EndPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);


hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (  NULL,  TEXT ( ".\\..\\..\\..\\slujob\\rbq\\grafika\\ramka vert.bmp" ),  IMAGE_BITMAP,  0,  0,  LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION  );
    if (hBitmap == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(IdGlavOkna, TEXT("Файл не найден"), TEXT("Загрузка изображения"), MB_OK | MB_ICONHAND);
        DestroyWindow(IdGlavOkna);
        return 1;
    }
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
hdc = GetDC(IdGlavOkna);
memBit = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(memBit, hBitmap);
ReleaseDC(IdGlavOkna, hdc);

//hdc = BeginPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);

BitBlt (  hdc,  0,  0,  WirinaRamki,  VysotaGlavOkna,  memBit,  0,  0,  SRCCOPY  );
BitBlt (  hdc,  WirinaGlavOkna - WirinaRamki,  0,  WirinaRamki,  VysotaGlavOkna,  memBit,  0,  0,  SRCCOPY  );

EndPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);
```

Что надо изменить, чтобы выводились картинки ramka goriz.bmp и ramka vert.bmp вместе?
[image: картинка из первого файла выводится] [image: картинка из второго файла выводится]

Comment: Я даже не обратил внимание.
Вы получаете hdc в beginpaint `hdc = BeginPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);` а потом перезаписываете эту переменную `hdc = GetDC(IdGlavOkna);`. Используйте 2 переменные вместо одной.

Comment: @zenden2k спасибо за подсказку. Возник вопрос: первым параметром BitBlt() должно быть hdc от BeginPaint() или от GetDC()? Я пробовал и так и так, оба варианта работают. Но какой из них верный?

Answer (score 3):

Может потому что вы 2 раза вызываете BeginPaint? Его нужно вызывать только 1 раз.

Вы получаете hdc в beginpaint `hdc = BeginPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);` а потом перезаписываете эту переменную `hdc = GetDC(IdGlavOkna);`. Используйте 2 переменные вместо одной.

Ну и еще пару замечаний:
Не надо загружать картинку из файла при каждой прорисовке (LoadImage ). Загрузите их предварительно в WM_CREATE или конструкторе. Аналогично про CreateCompatibleDC. Где вы уничтожаете созданные объекты? Если нигде, то возникает утечка памяти.

Если вы используете SelectObject, то вы должны сохранять то, что он возвращает (оригинальный объект) и восстанавливать после того, как закончили работу

Comment: Я закомментировал //EndPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps); и //hdc = BeginPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps);, чтобы BeginPaint  вызывать только 1 раз, но всё осталось по-прежнему.

Comment: С загрузкой картинки, CreateCompatibleDC и SelectObject я потом буду решать, мне бы пока с BitBlt() разобраться.

Comment: @0Zerro, отредактируй сообщение в соответствии с правками, внесёнными в код.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов: по Вашему предложению, я отредактировал сообщение - теперь строки EndPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps); и hdc = BeginPaint(IdGlavOkna, &ps); закомментированы.

Answer (score 1):

> > Возник вопрос: первым параметром BitBlt() должно быть hdc от BeginPaint() или от GetDC()?

Любой. Но если вы делаете это в рамках обработки сообщения WM_PAINT - то правильнее BeginPaint()/EndPaint(). В иных случаях допустимо GetDC().
ReleaseDC() вызывается только для GetDC() только один раз, когда тот уже не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, в чём была ошибка - ReleaseDC() вызывалась раньше чем надо. Несколько строк кода я изначально взял из текста, найденного в Интернете. Почитав умную книгу(Феня Юаня), понял, что в том тексте много ошибок. BeginPaint() и EndPaint() вообще не нужны, без них всё работает. Пока готов черновой вариант кода, буду дорабатывать. :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для правильной работы программы BeginPaint() и EndPaint() нужны, и всё это должно происходить в ответ на сообщение WM_PAINT.

Comment: @Антон Сазонов Спасибо за информацию, я уже изменил код соответствующим образом, он работает.